# Locality Sensitive Hashing using Random Projection method

Tags: python, hashcode

Can you review the following Python code?

````
import random

class Point3D:
    SEED = 1

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y
        self.Z = z

    def __hash__(self):
        hash_value = 0

        # Number of hash functions to use
        num_hashes = 5

        # Random vectors for projection
        vectors = [[0] * 3 for _ in range(num_hashes)]
        random.seed(Point3D.SEED)

        for i in range(num_hashes):
            for j in range(3):
                vectors[i][j] = random.uniform(-1, 1)  # Random value between -1 and 1

        # Compute hash value for each random vector
        for i in range(num_hashes):
            dot_product = self.X * vectors[i][0] + self.Y * vectors[i][1] + self.Z * vectors[i][2]
            hash_value <<= 1  # Left shift hash value by 1 bit
            if dot_product >= 0:
                hash_value |= 1  # Set the last bit to 1

        return hash_value

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.X},{self.Y},{self.Z})"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hash_set = set()

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                point = Point3D(i, j, k)
                hash_value = hash(point)
                # print(f"{count}--({i},{j},{k}) = {hash_value}")
                hash_set.add(hash_value)

    sorted_list = sorted(list(hash_set))

    print(f"Cont : {len(sorted_list)}")
    for item in sorted_list:
        print(f"{item:.2f}")
```
````

Answer (score 1):

If this code makes it into production,

```
random.seed(Point3D.SEED)
```

is eventually going to make someone very confused and then angry. Every hash call of every instance of your class modifies the global random state. The quick and bad fix is to reinstantiate and seed a new `Random` on every call to `__hash__`. The quick and less-bad fix is to set up your vectors once and store them as a static. This will also improve performance.

Without pulling in any other libraries or being tricky with C FFI, there are still some modifications you can make that should help with speed:

- Add `__slots__`
- Cache your hash value (this assumes that the class does not mutate, which may or may not hold - consider using `NamedTuple` to guarantee this)
- Loop like a native: unpack each vector row to its components with no indexing

Otherwise, some Python basics:

- Add typehints
- Use a set comprehension for your hash set test
- Don't cast `hash_set` to a list; `sorted` works fine on any iterable
- Convert your `Cont:` from a print to an `assert`, and add more of these (I have only shown one)
- `item` is an `int`, so just `print` it; don't `:.2f` format it
- Move the code from the `__main__` guard - which is still global - into a function

### Suggested

```py
from random import Random
from typing import Optional


def _make_vectors(seed: int = 1, num_hashes: int = 5) -> tuple[tuple[int, int, int], ...]:
    rand = Random(seed)
    return tuple(
        tuple(
            rand.uniform(-1, 1)
            for _ in range(3)
        )
        for _ in range(num_hashes)
    )


class Point3D:
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y', 'z', '_hash')

    VECTORS = _make_vectors()

    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, z: int) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self._hash: Optional[int] = None

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        if self._hash is None:
            hash_value = 0

            for vx, vy, vz in self.VECTORS:
                dot_product = self.x*vx + self.y*vy + self.z*vz
                hash_value <<= 1
                if dot_product >= 0:
                    hash_value |= 1
            self._hash = hash_value
        return self._hash

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"({self.x},{self.y},{self.z})"


def test() -> None:
    hash_set = {
        hash(Point3D(i, j, k))
        for i in range(3)
        for j in range(3)
        for k in range(3)
    }

    sorted_list = sorted(hash_set)
    assert len(sorted_list) == 9
    for item in sorted_list:
        print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

The above partially hides a problem, though: your hash function has a lot of collisions, and you can't see those collisions in any detail. Instead,

```py
    hash_set = Counter(
        hash(Point3D(i, j, k))
        for i in range(3)
        for j in range(3)
        for k in range(3)
    )
    print(hash_set)
```

```
Counter({22: 5, 16: 4, 18: 4, 5: 3, 1: 3, 4: 3, 20: 3, 31: 1, 17: 1})
```

Even at 100,000 hash iterations instead of five, there are still seven collisions.